# Expected class C# error

Tags: c#

Getting this error:
"expected class, delegate, enum, interface or struct", when try to run this:

```
using System;

static void Main()
    {
        int code = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Type...: ");
        code = (sbyte)Console.WriteLine();
            if (code == 1016){
            Console.WriteLine("y");
            } else {
            Console.WriteLine("n");
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to put your Main method into a  `class`.

Answer (score 2):

Your main Method needs to be wrapped in a Class

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {      
         int code = 0;
         Console.WriteLine("Type...: ");
         code = (sbyte)Console.WriteLine();
         if (code == 1016){
         Console.WriteLine("y");
         } else {
         Console.WriteLine("n");
    }
}
```